# vuejs return to parent component when @keyup on input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component with an input, when I press enter I get redirected to my parent component. Even when I put a @keyup I have exactly the same problem.

Is this because I'm in a child component?
How to disable the action of the enter key?

```
        <div class="form-field">
          <input v-model="userInput" :placeholder="$t('findCenter.placeholder')" type="text">
          <div class="btn primary" @click="getFromAddress()">{{ $t('findCenter.cta') }}</div>
        </div>
```

```
        <div class="form-field">
          <input @keyup.enter="getFromAddress()" v-model="userInput" :placeholder="$t('findCenter.placeholder')" type="text">
          <div class="btn primary" @click="getFromAddress()">{{ $t('findCenter.cta') }}</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some default behavior of an input or form submit you want to prevent you can use the `.stop` and/or `.prevent` [event modifiers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers) on the event so that it's default action should not be taken.  It can be done on the form itself, `<form @submit.prevent>` or on an input if a specific input is causing you trouble

Preventing default enter keydown behavior for your input:

```
<div class="form-field">
          <input v-model="userInput" :placeholder="$t('findCenter.placeholder')" type="text" @keydown.enter.prevent>
          <div class="btn primary" @click="getFromAddress()">{{ $t('findCenter.cta') }}</div>
        </div>
```